# How to add image as a button with transparent background in Xcode 11

Tags: swift, image, xcode11

Hope you can help. Very new to Swuift UI and Xcode

I am adding a an image in Xcode 11. I downloaded a vector image with a transparent background.
I have so far done the following.

1. Added vector JPG image to Media.xcassets
2. Changed the image to single scale
3. In mainstoryboard, I added UIImageView.
4. Changed changed image to JPG from step 1
5. Set background to default (transparent)

[Screenshot of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8z67.png)

When in simulation, image does not have a transparent background.

Comment: JPG not support transparency please use PNG

Comment: Hi, I have tried the abovesteps using a PNG also. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your PNG image?